FATXplorer not launching with wine
Launching FATXplorer via terminal I get:
/vagrant/mono/mono/eglib/gpath.c:115: assertion 'filename != NULL' failed twice.
How to fix this?

Check with https://www.winehq.org. Not all Windows programs are available through wine. This is not a Ubuntu problem, this is a wine problem.
